# Group extract using scala

Tags: regex, scala

Lets say I have the code:

```
val data = """^0001|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!^0002|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!^0003|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!"""
val pattern = """^\\^(\\w|)!$""".r
pattern.findAllIn(data).foreach(println)
```

How can I extract the group text which starts from `^` and ends with `!`
like I need the result as below:

```
Group 1 ^0001|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!  
Group 2 ^0002|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!
Group 3 ^0003|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!
```

Comment: Try regex, `(\^[\w|]+?!)`

Comment: @RAN_0915; Nice, but I quite don't see the point in making it a "reluctant" match: `+?` Greedy works just as well.

Comment: Should the match be group1, group2 etc or will group1 for each match also do? Or just the match like [this example](https://rextester.com/LKN46639)

Comment: @Thefourthbird it should be seperate group

Comment: This will give you 3 different capturing groups `(\^[^!]+!)(\^[^!]+!)(\^[^!]+!)`

Comment: The groups will be inifinte @Thefourthbird

Comment: Why don't you use a single capturing group [`(\^[^!]+!)`](https://rextester.com/MFKDC93436) for every match?

Comment: Use [`"""\^.*?!""".r`](https://ideone.com/ta5YqZ) or `"""\^[^!]*!""".r`

Comment: Btw, the number of groups will be FIXED since this amount is set by the number of capturing groups in your pattern (+1, the zeroth group is the whole match).

Comment: It is hard to come up with the best solution with only one example. For the given example it seems a simple `substring` will work since the  length of all three patterns are the same!

Comment: Please explain your scenario. As you see, you cannot get what you want, please let us know why you want that.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you.

```
scala> val data = """^0001|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!^0002|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!^0003|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!"""
data: String = ^0001|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!^0002|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!^0003|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!

scala> val pattern = """\^[^!]+?!""".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = \^[^!]+?!

scala> pattern.findAllIn(data).foreach(println)
^0001|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!
^0002|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!
^0003|1|0|813|1|860152033876093|!

scala>
```